# extra output when calling

Tags: java, timer, duplicates

OK I have been asked for an assignment to make a reflex game, which will allow the user to start and stop a timer then have their times displayed at the end. Currently it is mainly working, except currently there is a problem in which it will say push 1 to start as it is intended to and start my timer, but then it will display this message again before the number of seconds is displayed which is not intended. So if anyone could help or perhaps point out something which could be causing this would be appreciated

```
public class TimerTest {

    static int attempts = 4;
    static Timer timer = new Timer();
    static int controler;
    static int seconds = 1;
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int time1, time2, time3;

    public static void run() {

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {
                if (controler == 1) {
                    System.out.println(seconds++ + " seconds");
                }
            } // closed the running of timer

        }, 0, 1000);
        // closed timer

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println("\t\t\tthe rules\n");
        System.out.println("1) press 1 then enter to start the game");
        System.out.println("2) press 2 then enter as soon as you can to stop the timer");
        System.out.println("3)only enter the specified numbers none other");
        System.out.println("4) numbers only no letters\n\n");

        do {

            System.out.println("\t\t\tplease push 1 to start");
            controler = keyboard.nextInt();

            if (controler == 1 && attempts != 0) {

                run();
                attempts--;

            } else if (controler == 2 && attempts == 3) {

                System.out.println("stopped ");
                controler = controler + 1;
                System.out.println("your time is " + seconds);
                time1 = seconds;
                seconds = 0;

            } else if (controler == 2 && attempts == 2) {

                System.out.println("stopped ");
                controler = controler + 1;
                System.out.println("go 2 " + seconds);
                time2 = seconds;
                seconds = 0;

            } else if (controler == 2 && attempts == 1) {

                System.out.println("stopped ");
                controler = controler + 1;
                time3 = seconds;
                System.out.println("final go " + seconds);
                seconds = 0;
                attempts = 0;

            }

            System.out.println("\nyou have " + attempts + " attempts remaining\n");

        } while (attempts != 0);

        if (time1 > time2 && time1 > time3) {
            System.out.println("your first go was slowest with a time of " + time1 + " seconds");
        } else if (time2 > time1 && time2 > time3) {
            System.out.println("your second go was slowest with a time of " + time2 + " seconds");
        } else if (time3 > time1 && time3 > time2) {
            System.out.println("your final go was slowest with a time of " + time3 + " seconds");
        } else {
            System.out.println("STOP FUCKING UP MY PROGRAM JAVA");
        }

        if (attempts == 0) {
            System.out.println("\ngame over, thanks for playing and please try again");
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move

```
System.out.println("\t\t\tplease push 1 to start");
```

Outside of your do-while loop. Otherwise it's going to be printed everytime it iterates, which appears to be more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to iterate the while loop (and show your message) as many times as there are attempts:

put your statement in a condition, to only print when the controller is not 1.

```
if (controler != 1) {
    System.out.println("\t\t\tplease push 1 to start");
}
controler = keyboard.nextInt();
```

Also: be aware that you need to stop your timer somehow. Probably you want to keep a reference to it and call `timer.cancel()` when '2' is pressed.